# How to create json payload from python dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have an application where I run a query in AWS Athena and from the dataset, need to create a JSON payload to pass to a REST API.

The result-set format of AWS Athena is as follows:

```
order_id order_value product_currency order_email product_id product_quantity product_price product_name

123 22.0 INR abc@gmail.com 1A 1 12.0 Piano-set
123 22.0 INR abc@gmail.com 2A 2  4.0 Ludo
123 22.0 INR abc@gmail.com 3E 2  1.0 Toffee
234 45.0 EUR xyz@gmail.com 5T 1 45.0 Dumbbell-set
```

So an order can contain multiple products and each row represent an order with one product in it. So if an order contains 3 products, there are 3 rows with order data like order_id, total order value, order email being same, and the product information will be different.

So based on above dataset, I need to create a JSON payload in the following format:

```
Method: POST
Path: /invoice
Headers:
  - content-type: application/json
  
Body:
  {
    "data": {
      "value": "10.00", // orders_value
      "currency": "USD", // product[0]_currency
      "orderId": "123" // order_id
      "contents": [{
        "quantity": 1,
        "product_price": 10.0, // product_amount
        "title": "Piano-set", // product_name
      },
{
        "quantity": 1,
        "product_price": 10.0, // product_amount
        "title": "Ludo", // product_name
      },
{
        "quantity": 1,
        "product_price": 10.0, // product_amount
        "title": "Toffee", // product_name
      }],
      "company": "ABC"
    }
  }
```

If we observe for first order, there are 3 elements in contents for each product, whereas
order details are only repeated once. Similary for 2nd order, there will be only 1 element in the contents section. Please note that currency will be picked from any one of the product info, as all products will have same currency.

I get the entire AWS Athena dataset in a dataframe.

I was thinking of using a dictionary in python where key will be an Order object and value should be list of products. Since I am very new at python, was looking for advice on how to use objects in python as keys and objects.

Currently I am able to print the values returned from AWS Athena in the following way:

```
order_query_results_df = get_order_info('<company_name_value>')
                for index, row in order_query_results_df.iterrows():
                    logger.debug(row["order_id"])
                    logger.debug(row["order_value"])
                    logger.debug(row["product_currency"])
                    logger.debug(row["order_email"])
                    logger.debug(row["product_price"])
                    logger.debug(row["product_quantity"])
                    logger.debug(row["product_name"])
```

Please advise on the python snippet for the same.

Comment: From where the `"company": "ABC"` comes from? Also the price/value `10.0` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely - company - ABC is a hard-coded value, that will available to the python snippet. For all orders, that will remain same. order_value will be same for all rows, whereas product_price will be different for different products in an order.